# @InjectParam not working as expected

Tags: spring, tomcat, glassfish, jersey

I have a peculiar problem.The @InjectParam works on tomcat but not on glassfish.

It is just null in glassfish.
Any reasons for this?

public class RestControllers {

```
private static Log log=LogFactory.getLog(RestControllers.class.getName()); 
@InjectParam
private RulesController controller;
```

When I say controller.getSomething() is throwing NPE.

The controller.getSomething is throwing a null pointer exception only on glassfish. Works like a dream on tomcat.

Regards,

Avinash C

Comment: please provide more info as in do you get any error or what. Also provide some related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem myself. GlassFish apparently has no support for jersey annotations.

Just used Spring's ApplicationContextAware interface to get round the problem.

Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring

1) Please mention it is annotation driven

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.reports.controller"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in your application-context.xml

2) Use Spring @Autowired 
   Try to declare your service in the controller as below :

@Autowired
   ReportService reportService[As in the bean id of application Context ]